# PHP socket_recv return char* like C++

Tags: php, c++, sockets, char

I have an sockets code written in C++... but i want to convert to PHP.

Here is the C++ code if you want to analyze.

http://pastebin.com/hzX1A8mH

My current problem is.. make `socket_recv` return `(char*)` or something like c++ code.

C++ Code..

```
m_MsgSize = recv(socket, (char*)m_MsgBuf, 2, 0);
```

And in php?

```
$m_MsgSize = socket_recv($socket, ???, 2, 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any variable can go there, even one that has yet to be instantiatied.

eg:

```
$m_MsgSize = socket_recv($socket, $buffer, 2, 0);
```

In this case `$buffer` is passed to the function by reference and afterwards will contain the 2 bytes received.

Documentation:

- [`socket_recv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-recv.php)
- [References in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php)

Comment: But the next variable don't return the same value of running in C++.. `int datasize = m_MsgBuf[0] | m_MsgBuf[1] >> 8;` returns 0 in PHP and 23 on C++.. then i think that the problem is the buffer, or not?

Comment: @DjowYeap That depends. What does the buffer actually contain, and are you certain PHP is interpreting it how you think it should? IIRC C++ will perform the OR using the ordinal value of the character whereas PHP will try to cast it "as best as it can" which is *probably* a conversion from string to integer which will be zero for any character that's not a digit. Try `$datasize = ord($buffer[0]) | ord(buffer[1]) >> 8;` as the equivalent of your C++ code.

Comment: Also, if the size you're after is stored in a 2-byte binary string you probably want `$datasize = ord($buffer[0]) | ord(buffer[1]) << 8;` or simply `unpack('S', $buffer);`. http://ca1.php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php